# jquery parsing json data to table but i ve hidden columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I m coding a mobile app with jquery mobile and json.
I ve two different questions,

1) I ve a json data for example id, name, surname, point, mail and i ve a table to list this data, but in the begining i m hiding mail column in table, i ve a "columns to display" button. user can change columns to show. when i want to add a new data line, i m having problem with hidden column, i m using append(tr) method and this code makes new datas hidden columns visible.

2) my second question is, i m checking my json data with jsonlint and it says my data is ok! i have 2 different recors, but when i use this function, datam.lenght is 527 and datam[i].name is undefined.

```
function drawTable(datam) {
var tr;
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td>1 " + datam.id + " data l : "+ datam.length+"</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + datam[i].name + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + datam[i].latitude + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + datam[i].longitude+ "</td>");
    $('#mytbl').append(tr);
}
```

}

Comment: tr = $('<tr/>'); ? what are you doing here?

Comment: @Eric creating a table row, equivalent to `document.createElement("tr");`.

Comment: For your second question it sounds like you're passing in JSON rather than a JS object. You might want to `JSON.parse(json)`.

Comment: @Kriggs thanks didn't know that syntax

Comment: I think you should also put in your question the code that is using the drawTable function. Because we cannot know if `datam` is an object or an array or an array-like object

Comment: It is always said to create a string ind then append as innerHtml

Comment: Yes @Andy thanks, JSON.parse solved my second question, but i still cant solve first question.

Comment: You'll probably have to either update this question with code related to that point, or post a new question about it with the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

How are you hiding the mail column you talk about? Because if you perform a jQuery query to the DOM an then use 'hide' on them, it will only take effect upon the elements existing at the moment, not the elements that will be created after. You can have a variable to know if the column should or should not be displayed and add a class to the corresponding columns.

```js
var show = true;

function addRow()
{
    var tr = $('<tr/>'); //create row
    var td1 = $('<td>').text('new Col 1'); //create first col
    var td2 = $('<td>').text('new Col 2').addClass('optional'); //create second col
  
    if( !show )td2.addClass('hide'); //hide second col if show is false
  
    tr.append(td1);
    tr.append(td2);
  
    $('#mytbl').append(tr);
}

function toggleShow()
{
  
  show = !show;
  toggleDisplay();
}


function toggleDisplay(){
  if( !show ) $('#mytbl .optional').addClass('hide');
  else $('#mytbl  .optional').removeClass('hide');
}
```

```css
.hide
{
  display:none;
}

table td{
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>
<button onclick="toggleShow()">Hide Columns</button>
<table id="mytbl">
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td class="optional">Col 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```